# Android: NoClassDefError occurs in <4.0 but not >=4.0?

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a new intent from my Activity, but I get a NoClassDefFoundError.  The exception occurs resolving `MyClassB.class`.  Oddly I can resolve other classes, and the error only occurs in android versions 2.2 and 2.3, it works fine in 4.0+.

Both the class that causes the error and the other classes that resolve successfully are in the same package as the Activity where the code is executing.  Basically, the below code gives the below error on 2.2/2.3, but works fine on 4.0+.  I have also tried using the full package name like: `com.me.MyClassB.class`, but get the same error.

I realized this question is pretty vague, but am thoroughly confused and hoping that somebody might be able to help.

```
package com.me;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     protected onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
       super.onCreat(bundle);

        Class a = MyClassA.class;
        Class b = MyClassB.class;
    }
}


01-17 10:37:36.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1976): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.me.MyClassB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused because `MyClassB.class` implements `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener`.  It seems if classes contain certain code for a higher api level, they don't get setup properly at runtime, resulting in these sorts of errors.  I expecteded `MyClassB.class` to crash on 2.3, but the `NoClassDefFoundError` was particularly mystifying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but in your onCreate method you need to add `super.onCreate(bundle`) at the beginning e.g.

```
protected onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Class a = MyClassA.class;
        Class b = MyClassB.class;
}
```

Comment: this will solve other problems, but not the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.me.MyClassB

Comment: i edited my pseudo code to include this.  however, in my code, the "class a = ... " line executes fine, so that is definitely not the issue